# Is it possible to float, starting at an elevated point, with a board and enough strength?

Tags: forces

Premise: I have a structure like this.

```
   O
 _____
|     |
|     |
```

I'm the `O`, and I'm sitting on a flat surface or board while being supported by two poles. (it looks like I'm floating, but just imagine I'm sitting. it's hard to draw stuff with only characters! :P)

Now let's say one of the poles is removed.

```
   O
 _____
      |
      |
```

Of course, if nothing else happened then the structure would fall over. But what if I pulled up on the board?

```
             O/ < left arm
right arm > /______
            \/ ^for|ce
                   |
```

It's not a very good drawing, but my right arm is below the board, pulling up on it. Assuming that I was limitlessly strong, is it possible to not fall over? If so, is this possible?

```
              O
right arm > /___\ < left arm
            \/ \/
```

In other words, **is it possible to float, assuming you already start out elevated, with enough strength?** If not, why?

My research has been quite useless, although I think I have found the name for this kind of thing: [Bootstrapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping). That article is not particularly helpful though. [This question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/33279/is-it-possible-to-lift-yourself-off-from-the-ground) looks related, although I want to know whether this is theoretically possible with the aid of a board and when you are already elevated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's **not possible**, and the thing your analysis is missing is the reaction force the board has on your arm. Remember [Newton's Third Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_laws_of_motion#Newton.27s_third_law): If you pull the board with a force $\vec{F}$, it will pull you with a force $-\vec{F}$. In particular, if you are pulling with a force of, say, $300\ \mathrm{N}$ in the vertical direction with each arm to cancel your weight, then each arm will effectively weigh an extra $300\ \mathrm{N}$. The *net* force on the whole system will be unchanged.

Comment: ... so, essentially, you're trying to do [this](http://www.goethezeitportal.de/fileadmin/Images/db/wiss/bildende_kunst/illustrationen/muenchhausen/abenteuer_herrfurt_2/7_Muenchhausen_Herrfurth__500x789_.jpg).